# Android Emulator Galaxy s3 settings not using xhdpi assets

Tags: android

Based on Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing)
to test an xhdpi normal sized device , you have to have a skin of 640*960. If I do that, I see that my drawable-xhdpi assets are used.

However, a galaxy s3 emulator settings are WXGA720 skin with a density of 320. The drawable-xhdpi is NOT used for this emulator.  My CTO of my client has the new s3, so I'd like to be sure it worked before sending it over.
Any ideas of why s3 emulator doesn't use xhdpi assets?

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11193921/582571

Comment: not the same issue. I have color.png in the the resources. It is red in the hdpi folder, blue in the xhdpi.  It shows the red one instead of the blue one when I try to emulate an s3 with settings above.

Comment: did you try to put blue image inside drawable-large-hdpi ??

Comment: no cause s3 is an xhdpi device so it shouldn't get stuff from there. but I found a github project that has the same layout as me and just has a png that shows which folder it came from (mdpi,ldpi,hdpi,xhdpi) - it worked correctly in the emulators. So it must be projected related instead of emulator related.

Comment: https://github.com/blundell/ResBucket

Comment: Ever found out why it's like this? Because i'm having the same issue here...